# How the wcf blocks the client when IsOneWay=false?

Tags: c#, wcf

**Host** : has a function which is  : `IsOneWay=False`

this function when called  - pops a **MessageBox in the HOST**.

**Client** : has a winform that has **only button** that calls the Host's func.

if the function in the host IsOneWay=**true** - i can **multi press** the client button ( he **doesnt care** if i released the messagebox on the Host or not).

**but** if the IsOneWay=**False** - then he let me press **just once** ( **until** i release the MesageBox on the Host)..

```
host does he do that ?

How the Client knows that he should be blocked until the user releases the MessageBox on the Host side ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WCF host isn't responding to the client until the message box is dismissed.

If you were to break into the debugger on the client side you should see that your code is still within the WCF call to the host. If you waited long enough it would eventually time out. WCF can do this because `IsOneWay=false` requires the server to return before the client can continue executing. When `IsOneWay=true` the client sends the request and the server responds right away with success allowing the client to continue (before any server code is executed).

```
IsOneWay=false
   Client       Server
   ------    |  ------
1. click    --> method --> messagebox waits for OK
(client can't continue until server returns)
2. continue <-- method <-- user dismisses messagebox

IsOneWay=true
   Client     Server
   ------  |  ------
1. click  -->  method --> messagebox waits for OK
(client continues regardless of server state)
2. click  -->  method --> 2nd messagebox waits for OK
                          user dismisses messageboxes
etc...
```

Comment: if the Host and Client were in seperate Machines and the binding is HTTP , will my Client Button still be locked?

Comment: They should, yes. The client only continues after receiving a response from the server. From the client's perspective it could just be a long running database operation - it doesn't know that the server popped up a message box.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: I clarified it a bit. The server responds successfully right away so the client can disconnect and continue before any user code is executed.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - please convert your comment to answer and thanks

Comment: @ladislav : "The server responds successfully right away so the client can disconnect and continue before any user code is executed"   - but still if its 202 respose - he will still be locked , correct ?

Comment: @Mid787: No, when `IsOneWay=true`, HTTP 202 tells the client that the request was received and will be processed. The client will *not* be locked at that point. If `IsOneWay=false`, the client will wait for the server to execute the code and return HTTP 200 before continuing. You can look at [The effect of IsOneWay on Operations](http://kennyw.com/indigo/130) for more information.

Comment: @Joshua  , suppose  `IsOneWay=false` and he got the 202, how will the host will send him the 200  ? who is the initiator for the 200 ? i guess its the host  , but how a server can initiate a response? ( he already responded with 202...) ?

Comment: @Mid787, when `IsOneWay=false` a 202 will not be sent. The client will make a request and the server will wait to respond with the correct HTTP code after the executing code finished. This allows the server to respond with HTTP 200 (and the return value of the call, if there was one) or HTTP 500 if there was an exception.